# Spooler SubSystem App has stopped working - and print spooler keeps stopping with vague errors

Tags: windows-7

Problem:  Cant print.  The print spooler service will start, but when I want to view printers on the system, the spooler will stop and I usually get an error popup complaining about the "Spooler SubSystem App".  Its at that point the spooler service stops.   However, it starts back up fine.

Windows 7 64bit Pro.  At some point in the last few weeks, this problem started, but I do not recall at what point.  I know I have installed a few different apps since then, including some Microsoft development tools, as well as applied a few MS updates.

Ive been hitting google all morning, going through all the links, doing those things that have been discussed - including hacking the registry.  Restarted several times.  No luck.

Checking the Windows Application event log, I see errors like these

*Faulting application name: spoolsv.exe, version: 6.1.7601.17777, time stamp: 0x4f35fc1d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18247, time stamp: 0x521eaf24*

Other symptoms:
- When I turn the spooler back on, I browser to printers and I see a list of some of my network printers installed.  When the spooler stops, they all dissapear.
- When I restart the spooler and go into device manager, the spooler will stop.  I cant see the installed printer drivers.

Suggestions?

I suspect that one of the printer drivers is corrputed or needs to be updated etc, but the spooler wont stay up long enough for me to get to it to uninstall

Comment: Ok, I was able to one-by-one delete some of the printer drivers installed IF I restarted the spooler after each one.  I was using the printui command to view/uninstall the drivers.  The spooler seems to stay running by itself now.

Comment: follow this and give me a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57